# Nest aggregation not working correctly

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a use case where I need to do aggregation on multiple columns using C#.
I am using NEST libraries for this and I am facing the following issue

Query C# :

```
 var searchRequest = new SearchRequest
        {
            SearchType = SearchType.Count, 
            Filter = filter,
            Aggregations = new Dictionary<string, IAggregationContainer>
            {
                { "a", new AggregationContainer
                            {
                                ExtendedStats = new ExtendedStatsAggregator()
                                {
                                    Field = "a"
                                }
                            }
                },
               { "b", new AggregationContainer
                            {
                                ExtendedStats = new ExtendedStatsAggregator()
                                {
                                    Field = "b"
                                }
                            }
                }
            }
        };
```

When I receive response from NEST,  however I am getting only result for one aggregation. I am looking at SearchResult.Agg dictionary but it has only one entry for one aggregation field instead of two.
Let me know if I am missing soemthing or is it some issue with NEST libraries

Comment: Please let me know that one aggregation you getting in response

Comment: first aggreagtion gets retuned

Answer (score 0):

if you are using term aggregation then you need to use aggregation with filter.

```
var qryRes1 = client.Search<object>(x => x

                    .Aggregations(ag => ag
                           .Filter("filter", (flt => flt
                               .Filter(f =>
                               {
                                   FilterContainer filter = null;
                                    filter &= f.Query(qr => qr.Term(wl => wl.OnField("a").Value("the value you need to filter for field a")));
                                   return filter;
                               })
                                      .Aggregations(agr => agr

                                       .Terms("b", tr =>
                                       {
                                           TermsAggregationDescriptor<object> trmAggDescriptor = new TermsAggregationDescriptor<object>();
                                           trmAggDescriptor.Field("b");


                                           return trmAggDescriptor;
                                       }))))
                         ));
        var terms = qryRes1.Aggs.Filter("filter").Terms("b");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I print the SearchResponse.ConnectionStatus I can see that both the aggregations are returned. The problem I am facing is that my SearchResults.Aggs.ExtendendStats() has only details of first aggregation.

Comment: Some how the deserialization in NEST is dropping the second aggregation though the response correctly came from ES